# Netty: how do I reduce delay between consecutive messages from the server?

Tags: java, sockets, delay, netty

I'm on the dev team for a socket server which uses Netty.  When a client sends a request, and the server sends a single response, the round trip time is quite fast. (GOOD)  We recently noticed that if the request from the client triggers two messages from the server, even though the server writes both messages to the client at about the same time, there is a delay of more than 200ms between the first and second message arriving on the remote client.  When using a local client the two messages arrive at the same time.  If the remote client sends another request before the second message from the server arrives, that second message is sent immediately, but then the two messages from the new request are both sent with the delay of over 200ms.

Since it was noticed while using Netty 3.3.1, I tried upgrading to Netty 3.6.5 but I still see the same behavior.  We are using NIO, not OIO, because we need to be able to support large numbers of concurrent clients.

Is there a setting that we need to configure that will reduce that 200+ ms delay?

editing to add a code snippet.  I hope these are the most relevant parts.

```
@Override
public boolean openListener(final Protocol protocol,
        InetSocketAddress inetSocketAddress) throws Exception {
    ChannelFactory factory = new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(
            Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),
            Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),
            threadingConfiguration.getProcessorThreadCount());

    ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap(factory);

    final ChannelGroup channelGroup = new DefaultChannelGroup();
    bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new ChannelPipelineFactory() {
               .... lots of pipeline setup snipped ......
    });

    Channel channel = bootstrap.bind(inetSocketAddress);

    channelGroup.add(channel);

    channelGroups.add(channelGroup);

    bootstraps.add(bootstrap);

    return true;
}
```

The writer factory uses ChannelBuffers.dynamicBuffer(defaultMessageSize) for the buffer, and when we write a message it's Channels.write(channel, msg).

What else would be useful?  The developer who migrated the code to Netty is not currently available, and I'm trying to fill in.

Comment: Could you supply the applicable parts of your code?

Comment: When you say that both messages are written at about the same time, do you mean that `channel.write()` was invoked directly and completed for both requests at about the same time, or is there a layer in between this that is managing the writes in your code?

Comment: @increment1 : When I turned on debug level logging for the HexLoggingHandler, it logged each message immediately before calling super.writeRequested(ctx, e); where the super is SimpleChannelHandler.  The timestamps were 1 or 2 ms apart usually in my tests.

Comment: Are you sure the delay is on the server side? Have you  inspected the actual netowrk traffic with, for example, Wireshark?  Another observation: You seem to be creating a new ServerSocketFactory for each listener. That's expensive. Listeners of the same kind should probably share the same factory.

Comment: Wireshark on the client machine confirmed that the second message was arriving significantly later.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

200ms strikes me as the magic number of the Nagle's algorithm. Try setting the TcpNoDelay to true on both sides.

This is how you set the option for the server side.

```
    serverBootstrap.setOption("child.tcpNoDelay", true);
```

This is for the client side.

```
    clientBootStrap.setOption("tcpNoDelay", true);
```

Further reading: http://www.stuartcheshire.org/papers/NagleDelayedAck/

Comment: Usually Nagle’s Algorithm is a good idea to follow. Because Nagle’s Algorithm is to protect the network from stupid apps that do things like this, where a naive TCP stack might end up sending 100,000 one-byte packets... but you need to go beyond Nagle's algo for this particular use case. But you should read the last part of the mentioned url which says The importance of not disabling Nagle’s algorithm was spelled out in Greg Minshall’s email:...